# multiple image uploading nodejs reactjs multer

Tags: mysql, node.js, multer

I'm trying to make a upload image feature in my website. I've worked on uploading a single image and it worked how do I change my code to make it upload multiple images at same time code below:

Server Side:

```
// img storage confing
var imgconfig = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, "./uploads");
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, `image-${Date.now()}.${file.originalname}`)
    }
});


// img filter
const isImage = (req, file, callback) => {
    if (file.mimetype.startsWith("image")) {
        callback(null, true)
    } else {
        callback(null, Error("only image is allowd"))
    }
}

var upload = multer({
    storage: imgconfig,
    fileFilter: isImage
})



// register userdata
app.post("/insertImage", upload.single("photo"), (req, res) => {
    const { filename } = req.file;
    
    console.log(req.file)
});
Client Side:

  const [file, setFile] = useState("");

  const setimgfile = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0])
  }

  const addUserData = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("photo", file)

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      }
    }

    const res = await Axios.post("/insertImage", formData, config);

    if (res.data.status == 201) {
      console.log("NO error")
    } else {
      console.log("error")
    }
  }
```

REACT JSX

Here is my input file and multiple is added here
What should i do?? Please help me

```
<div style={{ padding: 15, backgroundColor: '#fff', marginTop: 15 }}>
            <h4>Upload file:</h4>
            <input type="file" name='photo' onChange={setimgfile} multiple/>
            <button onClick={addUserData}>submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

UI:

```
const [files, setFile] = useState("");
    
const setimgfile = (e) => {
  setFile(e.target.files)
}
    
const addUserData = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
    
  var formData = new FormData();
    
  for (const file of files) {
    formData.append('files', file)
  }
    
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
  }
    
  const res = await Axios.post("/insertImage", formData, config);
    
  if (res.data.status == 201) {
    console.log("NO error")
  } else {
    console.log("error")
  }
}

<div style={{ padding: 15, backgroundColor: '#fff', marginTop: 15 }}>
  <h4>Upload file:</h4>
  <input type="file" name='photo' onChange={setimgfile} multiple />
  <button onClick={addUserData}>submit</button>
</div>
```

BACKEND:

```
import multer from 'multer';
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    // Uploaded files destination
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const newFilename = `${new Date().getDate()}-${new Date().getMonth() + 1}-${new Date().getFullYear()}-${file.originalname}`;
    cb(null, newFilename);
  }
});
    
const upload = multer({ storage }).array('files');
    
app.post("/insertImage", upload, (req, res) => {
  console.log('success')
});
```